# How to create a timepicker using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascripting. 
I am using script in html code and i am using jQuery.js.
How to add a timepicker using the method in jQuery and what method is that?

Comment: A good first step might be to choose a timepicker plugin (there are several available) and to read the related documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

try this

Answer (score 1):

Two useful ones:

http://www.trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Comment: should be a comment, probably?